# convertir mysql_connect a mysqli_connect

Tags: php

hola necesito saber como canvertir este codigo a mysqli_connect

php

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if(!$link){
    echo 'No se puede establecer conexion con el servidor: '. mysql_error();
}else{
    $base = mysql_select_db('proveedores',$link);
    if(!$base){
        echo 'no se encontro la base de datos: '.mysql_error();
    }else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM proveedores";
        $ejecuta_sentencia = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$ejecuta_sentencia){
            echo'hay un error en la sentencia de sql: '.$sql;
        }else{
            $lista_paises = mysql_fetch_array($ejecuta_sentencia);
        }
    }
}

?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>contenido pedidos</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Pedidos</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>fecha</th>
                <th>hora</th>
                <?php
                for($i=0; $i<$lista_paises; $i++){
                    echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>";
                    echo$lista_paises['fecha'];
                    echo"</td>";
                    echo"<td>";
                    echo$lista_paises['hora'];
                    echo"</td>";
                    echo"</tr>";
                  $lista_paises = mysql_fetch_array($ejecuta_sentencia);  
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Fíjate en este fragmento de código: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

con este codigo **mysqli** conseguiras hacer lo que nececites , por cierto recomiendo  abandonar msql ya que es insegura, esta considerada obsoleta y eliminada en la version 7.1 de php.

la sintaxys es casi la misma solo cambian algunos parametros mira este ejemplo

```
$link =new mysqli('localhost','root','','your_db');
    if(!$link){
        echo 'No se puede establecer conexion con el servidor: '. mysqli_error();

        }else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM proveedores";
            $ejecuta_sentencia = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
            if(!$ejecuta_sentencia){
                echo'hay un error en la sentencia de sql: '.$sql;
            }else{
                $lista_paises = mysqli_fetch_array($ejecuta_sentencia);
            }
        }
    }
```

como veras la sintaxys es casi la misma aqui te dejo este articulo quisas te motive y te ayude [mysqli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona esto:

```
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='root';
$db='db_name'
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);
```